# Showing sub-level set of function is compact

Tags: analysis, convex-analysis

Let $X$ be a metric space and $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ be bounded from above with compact sub-level sets. Define a function $g: X \to \mathbb{R}$ by:
$$
g^h(x) = \sup_{y \in X} \{ h(y) - f(y) \} - (h(x) - f(x))
$$
where $h: X \to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function bounded from above. I need to show that $g^h$ also has compact sub-level sets. I proceeded as follows:
Set $a = \sup_{y \in X} \{ h(y) - f(y) \}$ and $b = \sup_{y \in X}\{H(y)\}$. Then for any $c \in \mathbb{R}$
$$
\{x \in X : g^h(x) \leq c \} = \{x \in X : f(x) \leq c - a +h(x)\} \subset \{ x \in X : f(x) \leq c-a+b \}
$$
Now we know that the rightmost set is compact from what we know of $f$. So it suffices to show that the leftmost set is closed. How would I go about this?